# Looking for info on the average decay energy of the Tauon

Tags: standard-model, leptons

I am interested in finding the average decay energy of the [Tauon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_(particle)). I am interested in the average net decay energy as a function of the known branching ratios of the tauon decay as well as the average actual decay energy in electron volts.

Comment: What do you mean by decay energy? If you just mean the total energy of the decay products, the answer is $m_\tau$, the mass of the particle, just as it is for every particle.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have discovered via the wikipedia link:
The 'bible' of particle data is supplied by the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/).
There you'll find reliable up-to-date extensive listings of all known properties of any particle, among which the [Tau](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/listings/rpp2017-list-tau.pdf).